# Magento2 UI component focusout event not working

Tags: magento2, javascript, uicomponent, knockoutjs, ui

I am using ui component for one the form in admin and for one element i am using component js class to trigger some operations on that element, it only gives onUpdate function, is there anything we can do if i want to trigger focusout event instead of onUpdate function? please find below screenshots for reference

[image: ui component xml file]

[image: component class]

Comment: the onUpdate do more than that, you can check the base Select component that you are extending from, also, read the template to see how that onUpdate trigger, it related to import/link in magento js

Comment: i have checked in core base files but i couldn't get anymore regarding other events that i can use